# Application of Fubini Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I neeed some help in trying to solve this problem :

Let $f$ be integrable over $(0,a)$ and $h(x)=\int_a^x\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$. Show that $h$ is integrable over $(0,a)$, and $\int_0^a h(x)dx=\int_0^a f(x)dx$.

My idea is to substitute $h(x)$ in $\int_0^a h(x)dx$

So we have $\int_0^a \int_a^x\frac{f(t)}{t}dt dx $.

I know I have to apply Funini’s Theorem but I dont know how to continue. Some help please?

Comment: What you do in these cases is introduce an indicator function, here for example you write $\int_a^x \dots \mathrm{d} t$ as $\int_a^\infty \dots 1_{[a, x]}(t) \mathrm{d}t$. You can then "switch" $t$ and $x$ in an adequate fashion in that indicator function when you're applying Fubini.

Comment: @BrunoB What is the reason of (t) in (t)dt?

Comment: It's $1_{[a,x]}(t) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } t \in [a,x]\\ 0 \text{ if} t \notin [a,x]\end{cases}$. Also I just realised that $x \leq a$ so I should have written $[x,a]$ instead of $[a,x]$ I guess.

Comment: @BrunoB What is the argument to switch t and x? Is the integral of that characteristic function finite?

Comment: You want to check that you can apply Fubini to the function $(x,t) \in [0,a]^2 \mapsto f(t)/t \cdot 1_{[x,a]}(t)$ (the indicator function is there to have fixed bounds on the integrals so that you can try to apply Fubini). And then you rewrite the indicator function so that it's a function of $x$ rather than of $t$, by doing what I described as "switching $t$ and $x$ in an adequate fashion" aka observing that $1_{[x,a]}(t) = 1_{0\leq x \leq t \leq a} = 1_{[0,t]}(x)$.